# Идет шагает по лесу. Шагает - это сказуемое или обстоятельство образа действия, или что?

Tags: синтаксис, сказуемые, обстоятельство

Каким членом предложения является *шагает*?

Comment: Осложненное ПГС  (простое глагольное сказуемое) с другим глаголом в личной форме стр. 68  https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/от%20преподавателей/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf

Comment: _**«Идет шагает…»**_ ? Лучше смотрелись бы такие варианты: _**идет-шагает…**_ или  _**идет, шагает…**_ …

Comment: @Слава то есть вы считаете, что лучше писать через дефис?

Comment: вот такой вариант еще встретил: идет — ковыляет

Comment: Буратино: _то есть вы считаете, что лучше писать через дефис?_ === Да. И вопрос о форме сказуемого сразу же отпадёт. 